# javascript variable show value in source code

Tags: javascript

I want to know how they add this code
[image: picture]

when I view the main source of the screenshot web page, some of the variables have a real value.
for example  `var last_price = 16740100`. When i refresh the source code, the value of `last_price` would change if it has been updated. I am curious how they add the value.
are they using php variable and pass it to javascript variable? or is there another way to set the value?

Comment: Most likely the page is generated by some server side language, yes. Which language it is we don't know.

Comment: The value is being set server-side and sent to the browser.  How it is added depends on the technologies in use.

Comment: that's an image, usually loaded using an `<img>` tag

Comment: so is it bad practice to add server side code to javascript? in my case i have ever tried using server side as value in javascript before, when i wanted to obfuscate the javascript code using some obfuscate app, the app tell the error that i cannot put php variable which meant that we are not allowed to add server side script at javascript.  @FelixKling

Comment: in php case, you just need to echo out the value e.g. `var javascript_variable = <?php echo 5; ?>` and you will have a server generated variable;